# How to update a column based on information on another table (DolphinDB)

Tags: dolphindb

I have two tables, **t1** and **t2**, they share the same column Code.
And what I would like to have is an update of the column totalValue from table **t1** with the sum of two columns (**t2**.value + totalValue).

```
>t1
code totalValue
---- ----------
A    10        
B    20        
C    30        
D    40        
E    50   

>t2
code value
---- -----
A    1    
C    2    
B    3    
D    4
```

Any idea what should be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
update t1 set totalValue=totalValue+t2.value from ej(t1,t2,`code)
```

another way:

```
update t1 set totalValue=totalValue+t2.value where t1.code=t2.code
```